# Error Missing Type specifer - int assumed . Note C++ does not support default init

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17

In order to make two objects, `User1` and `User2`, of a class `User` sending and receiving messages,

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class reply
{
public:
    User* sender;
 };


class User
{
    BlockingQueue<Message > queue;

public:
    
    void sendMessage()
    {
    };

    void run()
    { //...... 
    }

    


};
```

In the `Player` class, I get an error indicating that `Player* sender` is not a member of the `Message` class!

And in the `Message` class, i get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

    Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Use a forward declaration of `class Player;` before `class Message {`

Comment: Probably want `std::string` too unless there's a `using namespace std;` somewhere I don't see.

Comment: @RetiredNinja  it's  there in my code ! i just forget to add it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a forward declaration of player before Message

```
class Player; <<<<=====
class Message
{
public:

    Player* sender ;
    std::string text;
};
```

see here for explanation [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

and yes - it should be std::string